# How to format date string like 16/08/2018 14.29.30 to Datetime 2018-08-16 14:29:30 Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I convert date e.g. "16/08/2018 14.29.30" to Datetime 2018-08-16 14:29:30? I'having problem to convert '.' to ':'.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
s_date = '16/08/2018 14.29.30'
s_date = s_date.replace('.',':')
pd.to_datetime(s_date)
```

Result:
`Timestamp('2018-08-16 14:29:30')`

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1.** use `pandas.to_datetime` with `format` argument to specify strftime:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('16/08/2018 14.29.30', format='%d/%m/%Y %H.%M.%S')
```

**Option 2.** replace `.` with `:`, then pass to `to_datetime`:

```
pd.to_datetime('16/08/2018 14.29.30'.replace('.', ':'))
```

Both options return

```
    Timestamp('2018-08-16 14:29:30')
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. However, when I'm trying to apply this to the date column I'm getting ValueError: time data '16/08/2018 14.29.30' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H.%M.%S' (match)

Comment: Oh that's weird, that exact string is working in my test, both as a python string and as part of a DataFrame column! What pandas version are you using? I'm on 1.3.2 - not sure if that's the issue though.

Comment: it's working on a single test, but when I'm applying to the column it gets an error. I'm on 1.1.2 version.

Comment: Odd... Maybe a locale issue? (to check: `import locale; locale.getlocale()`) As a workaround, I suggest running this, assuming your date column is named `'date'`: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.replace('.', ':'))`

Comment: Thank you Peter, changing to .str.replace('.', ':') solved the issue.